# Intel HAXM - HAX version is too old

Tags: android, emulation, haxm

I can't start any x86 Android emulator on my laptop running Windows 7.

I have tried installing HAXM both through the extras folder in the Android SDK as well as directly downloading it from Intel's site and installing version 6.0.1 with no luck.

VT has been turned on in the Bios.

When I start an emulator I get the error

```
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX version (2) is too old (need at least 3).
```

If I run haxm_check.exe I get

```
VT support -- yes
NX support -- yes
```

Running sc query intelhaxm gives me

```
SERVICE_NAME: intelhaxm
    TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
    STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                            (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
    WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
    SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
    CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
    WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

I have VirtualBox installed, but VMVare is not running. I even stopped all the VMWare services.  I don't believe it's any antivirus problem.

Googling `HAX version (2) is too old (need at least 3)` shows this source code https://github.com/ashishb/android_emulator/blob/master/android/emulation/CpuAccelerator.cpp but can't glean anything from it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

The reason is that there was an old version of HAX driver (*version 2*) and the latest version of HAXM driver (file version 6.0.3, HAX driver *version 3*) is not installed successfully because it has some mismatch file name in its **intelhaxm.inf** file (see step 5) even if it says "install successfully" after you run the installer file on the machine.

Following are steps how did I fix the problem, step 1 to 3 are to remove the old driver and step 4 to 9 are to fix new version problem and install it, the `<android-sdk>` below should be your Android SDK directory.

1. Select **Computer** and Mouse right click menu, **Properties**->**Driver Manager**
2. Menu **View**->**Show hidden devices**, in the tree category **Non-Plug and Play Drivers**, find the `IntelHaxm` and uninstall the driver if found it.
3. Remove old intelhaxm driver folder: `C:\Windows\System32\DRVSTORE\intelhaxm_579C88F702D572C10DF6C9F1668B2077995F4354`
4. Go to `<android-sdk>\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager`  and extract the install file **intelhaxm-android.exe** to folder **intelhaxm-android** using *7-zip* or some other archive program
5. Go into the extracted folder **intelhaxm-android** and again, use 7-zip extract the **hax64.msi** to folder **hax64**
6. Go into folder **hax64** and remove all **.win7_64** suffix from the file names of the inf, sys, and cat files for your OS (win7 or vista), example for windows 7 64bit:

   - `intelhaxm.inf.win7_64` rename -> `intelhaxm.inf`
   - `intelhaxm.sys.win7_64` rename -> `intelhaxm.sys`
   - `intelhaxm_x86.cat.win7_64` rename -> `intelhaxm_x86.cat`
7. **The key step**: rename file `intelhaxm_x86.cat` to `IntelHaxm_x64.cat`. (Because file reference `CatalogFile.ntamd64=IntelHaxm_x64.cat` in **intelhaxm.inf** is actully **IntelHaxm_x64.cat** instead of *intelhaxm_x86.cat*)
8. Open a command window with Administrator privilege and run `sfc /SCANNOW` and then reboot the machine
9. After windows up, open a command window with Administrator privilege in that `<android-sdk>\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm-android\hax64` folder and run this command to install the driver `HaxInst64.exe /i intelhaxm.inf 1`, there should be no ERROR reported.
10. run this command to verify that it is working `sc query intelhaxm`, it should return with a state of 4 (Running)
11. Try to run **AVD manager.exe** in `<android-sdk>` to start your device simulator to check if works.

That's all.

Reference: [FIX HAXM 1.1.1 on Windows 7 64bit](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/android-applications-on-intel-architecture/topic/537144)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Android SDK 24.0.0 rc3. Turned out it has nothing to do with HAXM but SDK Tools which don't get the correct version.

I then downloaded SDK command line tools 24.4.1 from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads and copied all the files over my existing SDK (which was installed with Android Studio last week (android-studio-bundle-143.2915827-windows.exe)). Fun is, that Android Studio is not listing this update in the SDK Manager and says 24.0.0 rc3 is up-to-date.

After that launching an Emulator works with the SDKs default AVD Manager (located in the SDK root), but not from Android Studio. Android Studio still says my HAXM is out of date, it obviously does not recognize the correct version 6.0.1.

Please not that i'm not an Android Expert and have not yet tested any side-effects of the quick-and-dirty SDK Update. Maybe a fresh install of a seperate Android Studio and Android SDK is better.

Hope it resolves your issue as well.